# syslog clipping for particular applications

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, syslog-ng, centralized-logging

I have a few particular applications that are causing a LOT of logs in my syslog server. I would like to keep all of their logging in /var/log/messages or somewhere on the server, but I am trying to find a way to only send syslog messages to the syslog server for these apps if they are warning or above. Is there an entry I can enter into the syslog-ng.conf to parse out stuff below "warn" for particular apps?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit /etc/rsyslog.conf and change logs, example:

```
auth.*,authpriv.*                                       /var/log/auth.log
*.warn,*.err,*.crit,*.alert,*.emerg                     /var/log/syslog
daemon.warn,daemon.err,daemon.alert,daemon.emerg        /var/log/daemon.log
kern.warn,kern.err,kern.crit,kern.alert,kern.emerg      /var/log/kern.log
lpr.warn , lpr.err, lpr.crit, lpr.alert,lpr.emerg       /var/log/lpr.log
mail.warn,mail.err,mail.crit,mail.alert,mail.emerg      /var/log/mail.log
user.warn,user.err,user.crit,user.alert,user.emerg      /var/log/user.log
news.warn,news.err,news.crit,news.alert,news.emerg      /var/log/news.log
cron.warn,cron.err,cron.crit,cron.alert,cron.emerg      /var/log/cron.log
```

will log only `emerg` `crit` `warn` `alert` messages (except auth in this case)
if you change folders target, dont forget to update log rotate in `/etc/logrotate.d/` (if you have log rotate installed)

with this config you should not have lot of log. Else you have to worry about the messages you get

Comment: This is for rsyslog. Do you know if this same configuration work in syslog-ng ?

Comment: nop it is totally different  => https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/syslog-ng.conf.5.html, you should set the information more clear to avoid mistake like that ;)

Comment: I did mention in the issue as well as in the tag i was using syslog-ng. Your information is really helpful though I will have a look at the man page you sent.